# Third-party cookie method becoming obsolete to track users - what is next?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, tracking, privacy

Nowadays, people/companies behind the development of browsers are taking privacy in a serious way. They try to implement new security measures or simply change the default browser behaviours which have been around for a long time and today are considered as harmful for the privacy.

One example of this are third-party cookies. While IE requires a P3P policy to be sent when setting a cookie from a third-party domain, other browsers are blocking these cookies by default - or encouraging the user to activate such blocking option.

Also, if we think about extensions that help to prevent tracking (AdBlock, Ghostery...), it is getting more and more difficult to track users (whether for legitimate reasons or not).

As a developer, I found that there are some workarounds, such as [ETag](http://lucb1e.com/rp/cookielesscookies/), although as you may know already, there are ways to prevent this type of tracking. Local Storage, available in most modern browsers (the ones that support HTML5 + enabled JS), is another way to accomplish this.

I would like to ask you what method do you find better and why. I feel like Local Storage could be the best replacement to third-party cookies, as it stores persistent data (it is not cleaned after the browser is closed) and it works in the vast majority of browsers - but still a much smaller percentage that cookies. A LocalStorage+fallback_to_cookies seems to be the best way for me, but would like to hear more opinions.

Comment: I posted my "IMO" but I also voted to close, as this is mostly a matter of opinion, speculation, debate, etc.. and not really what SO is about.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I think this is an open question that could bring valuable insights about the future of tracking and privacy. I have seen similar questions about different topics in SO that were quite valuable in my opinion. Of course, if a moderator feels like this is not the proper site for this kind of questions, please feel free to go ahead and close this question.

Comment: Voted to leave open, but you really need to clarify what you're presently using 3rd-party local cookies for, and you need to use that to describe the actual problem, so that people may offer technical solutions to that problem.

e.g: If you're trying to implement single-sign-on, LocalStorage may not help you, because LocalStorage is domain-bound.

Answer (score 2):

localstorage isn't getting the same heat as cookies simply because it's a "newer" technology. Give it time and I guarantee you it will end up being blocked/removed the same way cookies are being blocked/removed.

So far first party cookies are relatively safe, though ultimately scripts like GA still make requests to GA server, and as you said, there are many plugins/extensions/addons that block them.

But IMO the future will be in server-side tracking solutions. For example, when you go to a web page, that's a request to the server. Lots of basic info can be grabbed from it already.  Then the javascript library would send (ajax) requests to the same server, not the 3rd party tracking server.  Then all this data would then be forwarded to the 3rd party tracking vendor (e.g. GA, Adobe Analytics, etc.) by a server-side script.

Many tracking script offer server-side solutions already, but it's little more than an API with (many times) vague documentation, since it's not as popular to go this route. So I think there will be a lot of development to more easily handle payloads from the client and make server-side requests, make it almost as easy to implement as the current js version.

The main sticking point is tying the info to a single visitor.  That's the most important part of the tracking cookies: a visitor ID that can tie all the activity together.  Thing is, the alternatives (using combinations of IP and header info) isn't that far behind the accuracy of cookies, when you measure it against the cookies being blocked, so it's not a *complete* loss to not rely on cookies in the first place.  But I think this will also have the affect of more and more websites enforcing a login system before a visitor does anything meaningful on their site.  This will allow them to use your login id as the visitor id and would actually stand to increase accuracy.

But overall.. it's more important to look at the trends in the numbers, not the actual numbers, and from that PoV, it's even less a big deal. Unfortunately, a lot of people forget this or don't understand this point.

Comment: I agree with you that LocalStorage will get the same _punishment_ as cookies nowadays. The part I do not see that clear is the server-side tracking solutions. Most of the people/companies can not afford (in all the possible meanings) to implement a server-side tracking solution, and the ones that can do it - there is no discussion about those, since the mentioned problem in OP is nonexistant. I am also aware about the fingerprinting _technique_ that would allow to individually identify users somehow and agree this would be an extra to help other kind of tracking methods.

Comment: @user2584228 well the bottom line is companies make an investment in their websites and they want to have more than guesses about what works and what doesn't in their marketing/design investments. The alternative is to simply stop investing in an online presence and I see that as even less likely to happen.  That's why I think ultimately, server-side solutions will get a lot more love as far as making it simple enough for more companies to implement.

Comment: Also, the server-side imps aren't really all *that* hard. The problem is a lot of (esp smaller) companies hire a 3rd party to dev their site  and then have someone on staff who isn't a dev put on a dev hat to do simple things like change copy, hoping they don't have to ever do any real dev tasks. I already see this problem all the time even as things stand now.  Even with the bulk of tracking being client-side, most custom imps require server-side code to pop js with data - a problem easily solved by hiring a real dev. Now..lack of funds is a legit (and unrelated) issue.. but just sayin'...

Comment: I was thinking exactly about that problem you are describing when I mentioned that most of the people/companies cannot _afford_ it, not only in an economical way but also technical. That is why server-side tracking is not feasible at least at this very moment. Bear in mind I am talking from the third-party tracking side, not like a developer who has his own webpage and could install Piwik or write my own software for my purposes.

Comment: @user2584228 well (in my experience anyways), piwik or rolling your own from-scratch solution is way harder than using a 3rd party server-side app.  If you have the resources to do the first 2, then you should definitely have the resources to do the last. I think the problem though, as you said, is that most small companies don't have the resources for any of those options. But like I said.. if things get bad enough to where client-side tracking is not worth it, and the choice is to go server-side or just not have an online presence.. I don't really see the latter as an option for most.